# AngularFire2 Observer

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The AngularFire2 documentation demonstrates the following pattern to bind an observer to your Firebase observable:

```
this.item = af.database.object('/item');

{{ (item | async)?.name }}
```

The async pipe unsubscribes when the component is destroyed, but what are the advantages/disadvantages of using the following pattern instead? And unsubscribing in the lifecycle hook `ngDestroy`?

```
af.database.object('/item')
.subscribe(item => this.item = item)

{{ item?.name }}
```

Comment: I have the same question. In my tests there is no difference between both other than boilerplate. The asynchronous pipe seems to subscribe and unsubscribe, however, what if you need to process the subscription in the code? In this case I feel you must manually describe. The async pipe doesn't seem helpful unless it is a pure template binding. I hope you get answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantage:** You can directly display the list to the template without subscribing it. It will save you time referencing it to a property. This pattern is used not only in AngularFire2 but in Angular 2 also. This is how **Observable** works.

**Disadvantage:** You can't manipulate the data within since you already displayed it directly. If you want to change something to the properties you need to use a pipe which take you time to create the logic.

Comment: + Advantage: You don't have to unsubscribe since the | async pipe will take care of it.